# Most convenient way to convert enumeration values to string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is about converting the enumeration values to a string array. I have an enumeration:

```
enum Weather {
    RAINY, SUNNY, STORMY
}
```

And I want to convert this to a string array with minimal effort and no loops with Java 8+. This is the best I came up with:

```
Arrays.stream(Weather.values()).map(Enum::toString).toArray(String[]::new)
```

Any other and similarly or more convenient ways to do the same thing?

Comment: Can you modify the enum? Just build the array inside the enum and supply a getter to retrieve it.

Comment: @christopher-schneider: I can. But that is not the point. My point is to create a minimal conversion, does not matter where it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Original post

Yes, that's a good Java 8 way, but...

The `toString` can be overridden, so you'd better go with `Weather::name` which returns the name of an enum constant (exactly as declared in the enum declaration) and can't be changed:

```
Stream.of(Weather.values()).map(Weather::name).toArray(String[]::new);
```

---

## A bit of generics

I wrote a helper class to deal with any enum in a generic way:

```
class EnumUtils {

    public static <T extends Enum<T>> String[] getStringValues(Class<T> enumClass) {
        return getStringValuesWithStringExtractor(enumClass, Enum::name);
    }

    public static <T extends Enum<T>> String[] getStringValuesWithStringExtractor(
            Class<T> enumClass,
            Function<? super T, String> extractor
    ) {
        return of(enumClass.getEnumConstants()).map(extractor).toArray(String[]::new);
    }

}
```

Here is a demonstration:

```
enum Weather {
    RAINY, SUNNY, STORMY;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(hashCode());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(EnumUtils.getStringValues(Weather.class)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(EnumUtils.getStringValuesWithStringExtractor(Weather.class, Weather::toString)));
    }

}
```

And the output:

```
[RAINY, SUNNY, STORMY]
[359023572, 305808283, 2111991224]
```

Comment: Thank you for the Stream.of idea. Regarding using ::name or ::toString, that is a bit debatable. Under certain circumstances you might want to be able to change the string representation.

Comment: @gil.fernandes, yes, good point - if you want to represent these values dynamically, use any `String` extraction function (like the `toString`), otherwise, use the final `name`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're frequently converting enum values to any kind of array you can as well precompute it values as static field:

```
enum Weather {
    RAINY, SUNNY, STORMY;
    
    public static final String[] STRINGS = Arrays.stream(Weather.values())
                                                 .map(Enum::name)
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                                 .toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

And use it just like that `Weather.STRINGS;`.